# Jquery/C# Making a webService call errors out: cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, jquery, serialization

Here's my call:

```
CallMfttService("ServiceLayer/FieldingManager.asmx/GetUICs",null, SetUicValues);
```

Here's the WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public List<string> GetUICs()
{
    UserManager user = new UserManager();
    var currentUser = user.GetUser(Security.FieldingToolPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name);
    List<string> uics = new List<string>();
    uics = Data.FieldingManager.SelectUicByJpm(currentUser.Organization);

    return uics;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.. I know it obviously doesn't like sending no paramters..I really don't know though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the I need to send empty braces to the method.

```
CallMfttService("ServiceLayer/FieldingManager.asmx/GetUICs", "{}", SetUicValues);
```

the "{}" fixed the issue.. thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `null` with `new object[0]` in your call:

```
CallMfttService("ServiceLayer/FieldingManager.asmx/GetUICs", new object[0], SetUicValues);
```

Comment: That didn't work either. That just causes my page layout to get all funky. The javascript error is "Object Expected". Since my web method doesn't takes parameters how does sending a new object as a parameter help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely this:

```
Data.FieldingManager.SelectUicByJpm(currentUser.Organization);
```

The object you're returning, "uics", probably doesn't have a blank constructor. That is, a new with no parameters:

```
new UicObject();
```

Giving it one should fix your problem.